# How can I assign a keyboard shortcut to increase/decrease the brightness of both my monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11, autohotkey

I'm using a desktop PC with Windows 11 Home (22H2). I like operating my PC using keyboard shortcuts. I have used [AutoHotkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey) (AHK) to control several things, such as increasing/decreasing the volume (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>/<kbd>F12</kbd>, moving to the next multimedia track (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>), etc.

However, I do not know how to assign a keyboard shortcut to increase/decrease the brightness of my monitors at will. For now, I'm using a simple, but powerful, tool called [Monitorian](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/monitorian/9NW33J738BL0?hl=en-gb&gl=gb&rtc=1) to do that. It works fine, but I would like to achieve the same result using keyboard shortcuts, e.g., by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>/<kbd>F2</kbd>.

Is there a way to do this?

I will accept any answer no matter if it uses the default Windows or a third-party tool (AutoHotkey or other) as long as the result is the intended one. **Important:** I'm using two monitors and I would like to control the brightness of ***both*** monitors with the same keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with AutoHotKey and NirSoft's `ControlMyMonitor.exe`.

[NirSoft](https://www.nirsoft.net/) puts out lots of useful utilities like [ControlMyMonitor.exe](https://www.nirsoft.net/articles/change_monitor_brightness_command_line.html).

Answer (score 11):

I have marked [Keltari's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1764288/how-can-i-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-increase-decrease-the-brightness-of-both/1764293#1764293) as the correct one as it led me to the solution, but for completeness' sake here's what you have to do to make this work with AutoHotkey.

First, you have to create a .bat file with the commands that increase/decrease your monitor's brightness. For my two monitors, all I had to type was:

```
"[PATH TO ControlMyMonitor.exe]" /ChangeValue Primary 10 5

"[PATH TO ControlMyMonitor.exe]" /ChangeValue Secondary 10 5
```

and saving it as `increase_brightness_5.bat`. This bat file simply increases the brightness of both my monitors by 5. Do the same for a bat file that decreases the brightness.

Then, go to your AutoHotkey script and assign a keyboard shortcut to run that bat file. For me, that was:

```
; Decrease brightness by 5
#f1::Run, "[PATH TO decrease_brightness_5.bat]",,hide

; Increase brightness by 5
#f2::Run, "[PATH TO increase_brightness_5.bat]",,hide
```

Basically I'm using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to increase the brightness and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to decrease it. This `,,hide` hides the console window.

Comment: There is no need for the batch file; you can simply pass parameters as part of the [Run command](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/Run.htm).

Answer (score 5):

I know there's already an answer, and despite being an avid fan and user of AHK myself, I thought I'd share another utility that is capable of achieving the same effect on its own:

[EasyMCC](https://bluesky-soft.com/en/EasyMCC.html)

For link retention, I've hosted a copy of version 2.4.0 [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Y0vdLEmcTgy8nZljflar33GPiq_nxo3/view).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I set the script up:

; make sure you put the ControlMyMonitor.exe file in the same directory as your script

; Decrease brightness by 5
^Up::Run, ControlMyMonitor.exe /ChangeValue Primary 10 5 ,,hide

; Increase brightness by 5
^Down::Run, ControlMyMonitor.exe /ChangeValue Primary 10 -5 ,,hide

thx @Aventinus

Comment: I cant see how this adds any new information.